# Cocos2d Android Add background in portrait orientation

Tags: java, android, background, cocos2d-android

Hi I have a problem when I try to add a background to using cocos2d.
I followed the tutorial Denvycom doing a puzzle but with landscape orientation.

http://denvycom.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-build-your-first-slider-puzzle-game-in-cocos2d-for-android-part-1/

I try to make a game with portrait orientation does not work.

My code:

MainActivity.java

```
protected CCGLSurfaceView _glSurfaceView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    _glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(_glSurfaceView);


    CCDirector director = CCDirector.sharedDirector();
    director.attachInView(_glSurfaceView);
    director.setDeviceOrientation(CCDirector.kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait); // set orientation      

    CCScene scene = GameLayer.scene(); //
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene); 
}//fin oncreate
```

GameLayer.java

```
public class GameLayer extends CCLayer{

private static CGSize screenSize;
float generalscalefactor = 0.0f ; 

public GameLayer () {
    screenSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();


    generalscalefactor  = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize().height / 500 ; 
    CCSprite background = CCSprite.sprite("bggreen.jpg");
    background.setScale(screenSize.width / background.getContentSize().width);      
    background.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0f,0f)) ;
    background.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(0,0));
    addChild(background);
}


public static CCScene scene()
{
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    CCLayer layer = new GameLayer();
    scene.addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

}
```

Can you help me?
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your AndroidManifest.xml file has this line in your activity tag?

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But this is no problem. The application only runs on portratit by 'director.setDeviceOrientation (CCDirector.kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait);'

Answer (score 0):

The answer you can find it here

[Black Screen on Android Launch Unless using Landscape Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137441/black-screen-on-android-launch-unless-using-landscape-orientation)

The problem came from the api version of the phone.